# zk snark desgined for Exponentiation computation

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I know that there are papers for both theoretic and practical zk snark computation. 
 And most of them could support general computations. i.e: support multiplication and addition 
But what I am curious about is that are there papers/constructions that optimize the exponentiation computation, not just having a^n computed as a*a...*a? 
Thanks a lot